# How to upload file using Protractor to the ng-file-upload element

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, protractor, end-to-end

The HTML is as follows:
`<input type="file" style="display: none" ng-file-select="" ng-file-change="upload($files)" ng-multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg,.png">`

I need to upload file to the element which uses [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload#contrib) for uploading image file using Protractor:

```
var uploadFile = element(by.css('input[type="file"]'));
uploadFile.sendKeys('C:\\Temp\\test.png');
uploadFile.evaluate("openMetadataDialog({file:imgFile})");
```

The above is however not working. I am not able to understand how to upload the file!
As per my understanding, as soon as I sendkeys to input element, the upload function should be called itself! However, that does not seem to be happening!

Regards,
Sakshi

Comment: I am not sure about the 3rd line - why are you calling `openMetadataDialog()`? Is there a submit button on a form that contains the file input? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. There is a Submit button which sends the File and some metadata regarding the file(description etc)

Comment: I think you just need to click that submit button after sending keys to the file input.

Comment: That used to work when ng-file-upload was not used at the backend for file upload.

Comment: @alecxe: Any idea bout the above info? Is there a way in which I can pass a new File() parameter to openMetadataDialog function?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure why you cannot submit the form normally and there is a need to call `evaluate()`..thanks.

Comment: @alecxe: If I dont call this function, then the required dialog doesn't open(which opens automatically when I upload a file manually). Although, what I really think is that as soon as I sendKeys to the input, the upload() function should be automatically called(ng-file-change="upload($files)") but this doesn't seems to be happening. So, I guess I am doing something wrong!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Have you tried to use `executeScript()` instead of `evaluate()`?

Comment: I tried. But it doesnt seem to work at all. Btw, what difference will it make to use executeScript() instead of evaluate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that ng-file-upload doesn't react to `.sendKeys(...)`, its file-change doesn't get invoked. You can use standard `onchange` event to invoke some custom upload logic:

```
<input type="file" 
       style="display: none"     
       onchange="angular.element(this).scope().upload(this)" 
       ng-file-select 
       ng-multiple="multiple" 
       accept=".jpg,.png">
```

*this* points to the input element which has a property *files*.